# Git error: failed to push some refs when mirroring a repository

Tags: git, push, versioning, mirror

I'm not very experienced with git but set up a public mirror of a private repository a few months ago and now want to update it to the current status of the private repository.

I'm following the instructions here and pretty sure this is what I followed when initially creating the mirror:

- [Mirroring a repository](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/creating-and-managing-repositories/duplicating-a-repository#mirroring-a-repository)

However, this time when I execute the following:

```
git clone --mirror https://github.com/billtubbs/process-observers.git
cd process-observers.git/
git push --mirror https://github.com/billtubbs/ml-obs.git
```

I get

```
Enumerating objects: 991, done.
Counting objects: 100% (991/991), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (261/261), done.
Writing objects: 100% (938/938), 2.27 MiB | 2.67 MiB/s, done.
Total 938 (delta 724), reused 889 (delta 677)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (724/724), completed with 40 local objects.
To https://github.com/billtubbs/ml-obs.git
 + 74c80ea...9ff3e6b main -> main (forced update)
   dce6fcc..9ff3e6b  origin/main -> origin/main
 * [new branch]      origin/HEAD -> origin/HEAD
 ! [remote rejected] refs/pull/1/head -> refs/pull/1/head (deny updating a hidden ref)
 ! [remote rejected] refs/pull/2/head -> refs/pull/2/head (deny updating a hidden ref)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/billtubbs/ml-obs.git'
```

What does this mean "failed to push some refs to ..."?

All the files seem to be updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing has actually gone wrong in terms of copying the commits.  What's happened here is that your mirror clone included all the pull request commits available in the original repository;<sup>1</sup> your subsequent `git push` tried to send those commits *and* the names used to find them to the new repository on GitHub, but GitHub tightly control those names, so they rejected the attempt to create such names.

The original PR commits are lost from the new copy, but this will always be the case when using this method to copy a GitHub repository.

One thing that *did* go slightly wrong—this is not too serious—is that you've created two bogus branch names in the new GitHub repository:

> ```
>    dce6fcc..9ff3e6b  origin/main -> origin/main
>  * [new branch]      origin/HEAD -> origin/HEAD
> ```

The first line shows that you've update a branch name `origin/main` in the GitHub repository, and you don't want that.  (It was already there, for whatever reason, probably created by your original sequence.)  The second line shows that you created a new branch name `origin/HEAD` in the GitHub repository.

While there's nothing actually *broken* by having such a name, these names are extremely confusing to users, who wind up with `origin/origin/main` and `origin/origin/HEAD` remote-tracking names in *their* clones.  So it's a good idea to delete these two branch names from the GitHub repository, so that people cloning it don't get these weird, difficult-to-use, difficult-to-deal-with names.

---

<sup>1</sup>As [flotho answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74200749/1256452), the GitHub instructions say to use `git clone --bare`, not `git clone --mirror`.  Using `--bare` avoids copying these extra names.  The extra-name-copying wasn't actually *harmful* though, except in terms of causing the subsequent complaints.

Comment: Indeed.  My mistake.  And you are right, I didn't want all those commits!

Comment: I ended up deleting the mirrored GitHub repo and recreating it from scratch, this time using `git clone --bare` and there were no errors but it still copied all the commit history. So the history is copied just not the names and where it came from?

Comment: Both `--bare` and `--mirror` make a bare repository. The set of commits that go into the clone are those *reachable from* the *names* that get copied; by default, `--bare` copies all *branch and tag names* but no other names, while `--mirror` copies all names. On the GitHub side, the repository's names are branch names, tag names, and special GitHub names. So the mirror clone will pick up any commits reachable only from the special names, while the bare clone will omit those. But since you can't *write* the special names *back*, the effect is pretty much the same.

Comment: History, in any Git repository, consists of the commits in the repository. So the mirror clone has a little more history: it includes the PR commits. But given that you can't put them back... well!

Answer (score 1):

I think you might have made a small mistake following the docs.

Try to change the option `--mirror` to `--bare` in the `git clone` command.

Just like is written in the docs:

> 2. Create a bare clone of the repository.
>    `$ git clone --bare https://github.com/EXAMPLE-USER/OLD-REPOSITORY.git`